# How to position the background image for HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css

I just designed my first prototype of a website. I designed it on Figma and chose the desktop layout.
See The Final Prototype
[image]

But as I put the background on the CSS code its gets stretched to the screen.
See The Screenshot

[image]

So how do I adjust the size of the background image so that I get the exact background as seen on the final prototype to add logo and nav menu
This is the Background

[image]

I'm a complete beginner to CSS.

Comment: Show us the code you tried!

Comment: Without seeing your code, we will be guessing. Please provide a [MCVE]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use below code snippet

```css
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.banner {
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7afd.png"); 
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<div class="banner"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried CSS 
background-size: cover;

Refer below link:

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you show the code that you are using, but I am guessing that you are looking for something like:

```
body {
  background-position: center; /* Center the image */
  background-repeat: no-repeat; /* Do not repeat the image */
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body, html {
    background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7afd.png");
    /* Full height */
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;    
    margin: 0;


    /* Center and scale the image nicely */
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>This is a heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

there is your code